# how to parse tcp packet payload in c

Tags: c, sockets, memcpy, string-parsing

I want to write a c program that receives a TCP protocol data and parses the header and body. To do that i created packet structures to represent header and body fields :

```
struct header {
  unsigned int command_length:32;
  unsigned int command_id:32;
  unsigned int command_status:32;
  unsigned int sequence_number:32; };

struct bind_transceiver {
  char System_id;
  char password;
  char system_type;
  int interface_version;
  int addr_ton;
  int addr_npi;
  char address_range; };

struct packet {
  struct header header; 
  char body[91]; };
```

When the server socket receives data, it stores it in a char variable named *buff*. Then it sends *buff* to *header_parse* function for parsing :

```
#define MAX_SIZE 10000
... 
...
char buff[MAX_SIZE];
read(sockfd, buff, MAX_SIZE);
header_parse (sockfd, buff);
```

In *header_parse* function, i create a packet struct and copy *buff* to it using *memcopy*

```
header_parse (int sockfd,  void *data ){
  struct packet *_packet;
  _packet = calloc (1, sizeof (struct packet));
  memcpy (_packet, data,  sizeof(data) );
...
}
```

The header is copied correctly and i can print them using these lines :

```
fprintf (file, "command_length : %d\n", _packet->header.command_length);
fprintf (file, "command_id : %d\n",  _packet->header.command_id);
fprintf (file, "command_status : %d\n", _packet->header.command_status);
fprintf (file, "sequence_number : %d\n", _packet->header.sequence_number);
```

According to the command_id value , i send *_packet* to specific function to parse body :

```
if ( _packet->header.command_id == 150994944 ) {
    bind_transceiver(sockfd, _packet );
}
```

In *bind_transceiver* function, **the parsing can not occurred** . i tried to print it byte by byte . but it's empty or contains value of another variables in program.

```
void bind_transceiver (int sockfd, struct packet *_packet) {
  for (i=0; i<91; i++) {
    fprintf (file, "***%s\n", &_packet->body[i] );
} }
```

The body fields content does not have fix length and i can't extract the body like header. Is there a solution to**extract TCP packet payload** in this case ?

Comment: `sizeof(data)` gives you the size of the pointer, are you expecting this?

Comment: Could you please provide a code that actually receives the packet from socket? Cause it could matter whether you firstly reading a header, parsing it, and then receiving an appropriate body, or you receiving an entire packet at once.

Comment: @NickS i changed *sizeof(data)* to *sizeof( struct packet)* and now i can get body content.  i can parse body fields in a  custom way : i find empty locations in body and save the next location of them to an array as start points of fields. then i use these numbers as body index and print them. is there another way to extract tcp stream ?

Comment: @ Henadzi Matuts i receive  entire packet at once using this : read(sockfd, buff, MAX_SIZE); i already edit question too.

Comment: @F_yaghoubkhani, if I understood you correctly, you just need to cast your _packet->body to struct bind_transceiver* type (i.e. declare a variable in your bind_transceiver like this: struct bind_transceiver *bind_tranceiver_body = (struct bind_transceiver*)_packet->body), then you can just access your bind_transceiver fields like: bind_tranceiver_body->System_id, bind_tranceiver_body->password, etc.

Comment: @F_yaghoubkhani, Moreover, common way of doing such things is using a union in your packet struct. instead of char body[91] field you can have: union {char body[91], struct bind_transceiver bind_tranceiver_body}. Then, after getting the body type from header, you can just access the body like _packet->bind_tranceiver_body for bind_transceiver command id, and _packet->body for raw body bytes.

Comment: @Henadzi Matuts,thank you for your response. I done the same thing you say. i created a structure that represents packet fields. when memcopy received tcp stream to the structure, the header is matched correctly all the time. but the start location of each field in body depends on the content length of the field.

Comment: @Henadzi Matuts, for example if *system_id* be *"abc"* , the start location of next field will be *body[3]*, but if  *system_id* be *"abcd"* , the start location of next field will be *body[4]* and there is no fix length for body fields like header and at the result i can not predict the tcp packet body how will be . it's the main problem.

Comment: Oh, now I see the problem. I have 2 more questions though, do you have zero-terminated strings in a payload? and is it possible to modify actual packet structure?

Comment: Henadzi Matuts, yes,when i print out the body byte by byte, there are some null locations.  yes i can modify packet structure if needed.